# Add new data to existing Power Query

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

Sorry, this is probably a really basic question , im geuessing. How can i use an existing power query on as new excel file? i have tried going to Data > From File > Excel Workbook. It asks me create a new query how can i use the existing query called "Query Test".

[image]

How can i use the already create query called "Query Test" on new data ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities, depending on what exactly you mean by "use".

Probably the easiest is Copy and Paste - right-click the entry in the Queries & Connections pane and choose Copy.  Then you can right-click and paste there again to duplicate the query, or do the same in a separate file if that is what you are trying to achieve.